# Performing Summation Over Wavevectors of Internal Energy

Tags: python, physics

The task my code is supposed to perform is computing the sum over wavevectors of the internal energy of a harmonic oscillators following a Bose-Einstein distribution. This is a sum over k of h*w(k)*n(k), where w^2(k) = 4*sin^2(k/2), n(k) =1/(exp(h*w/kb*T)-1), and h is really the reduced Planck constant and kb is Boltzmann's constant. The system is a 1D chain of oscillators of Length L, so N-1 possible oscillators, with fixed boundary conditions so that the possible wavevectors are pi\L to (N-1)*pi/L. My code to implement this summation is given below. The issue is that it produces a linear internal energy, but we proved in class that the temperature dependence must be quadratic at least at low temperature, using the Debye model.

```
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.constants import hbar, Boltzmann
L_ = np.array([5,10,20,50,100]) #Possible lengths of the chain
#N=L-2 # N-1 is the number of oscillating particles in the chain of length L=(N+1)*a
T= np.array(np.arange(0.00001,1000,0.01)) ## Temperature in Kelvin
Constant = Boltzmann/np.sqrt(4*pow(hbar,2))
Y =hbar/Boltzmann 
def U(T,L): 
    U =0
    for m in range(1,L-1): ## k range for excitations
        w = 2*abs(np.sin((m*np.pi/L)/2))
        n = 1/(np.exp(Y*w/T)-1)
        U += hbar*w*n 
   return U
def Debye(T,L):
     return L*(Boltzmann*T)**2 *(np.pi/6)
for L in L_:
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(T,Debye(T,L),label="Debye L="+str(L))
    plt.plot(T,U(T,L))
    plt.title("Internal Energy for L=" +str(L))
    plt.xlabel("$k_B$T/$\sqrt{4C\hbar^2/M}$")
    plt.ylabel("$U(T)$")
    plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your temperature range is inappropriate - 1000 K is not usually considered to be "low" temperature. Try something like 10 K or 1 K instead. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debye_model#High-temperature_limit) explains why the behaviour you saw was linear.

(The article also says the low-temperature relation is *cubic* instead of quadratic, but this is not too important for the purpose of this question.)